# lack of a controller for index page in angular, cannot use ng if

Tags: angularjs

My index page doesnt have a controller, it contains the `header tag` and below that header is the `div tag` for ng-view.

However I have some div I want to hide/show (using data-ng-if) depending on the parameters stored in the sessionStorage.

```
    $window = $windowProvider.$get();
    var tokenString = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userinfo'));
    tokenString.AccessPara = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
```

in Index.html:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li data-ng-if="tokenString.AccessPara.indexOf('test1') !== -1"><a href="#BrokerageSearch">test1</a></li>
       </ul>
```

I dont have a controller for the index page, so how do I pass in a scope or a variable for the view to read and determine whether to show or hide the `li tag`. Can I maybe put it in the appName.config?

Comment: You can bind tokenString to $rootScope in this way `$rootScope.tokenString` , in this way you will be able to access tokenString from your view.

Comment: where do I initialize that though? in the App.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to gather that data somewhere, don't you?

If you don't want to use a component approach and encapsulate that behaviour in a separated component (what I highly encourage, as I find it the cleanest solution), you can inject a *$rootScope* into a service (or anything else) that will be gathering the data ant then set it like this:

```
$window = $windowProvider.$get();
var tokenString = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userinfo'));
tokenString.AccessPara = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

$rootScope.tokenString = tokenString;
```

Then you can use it in the html, just like in the example that you supplied.

However it's not a good thing to use *$rootScope* at all

Another idea is to set a controller on the `<body>` tag for example and do the same but using a *$scope*.

Comment: where should I initialize the variable into the rootscope, so that the index page will have it before it loads/render?

Comment: You don't want to do that in the config, because in the config you can inject only providers. The application has to be bootstraped, so basically you will need some controller somewhere. You can register a controller on the route (if you are using $routeProvider) or as I said on the html element like body with ng-controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically add controller:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="AwesomeController">
            <li data-ng-if="tokenString.AccessPara.indexOf('test1') !== -1"><a href="#BrokerageSearch">test1</a></li>
       </ul>
```

P.S. you can also do it with directive, component or whatever.